# manipulating two dictionaries in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
dict1 = {'groceries': ['apples', 'oranges', 'tomatoes'], 'supplies': ['notebook', 'pencil', 'tape']}

dict2 = {'apples': 2.99, 'tomatoes': 1.29, 'notebook': 3.15}
```

what I'm trying to accomplish is if a key in `dict2` (e.g. `'apples'`) matches one of the values in `dict1`, then the corresponding value in `dict2` (e.g. `2.99`) gets summed for the key in `dict1` (e.g. `'groceries'`).

so in this example, I want the result to be a new dictionary:

```
dict3 = {'groceries': 4.28, 'supplies': 3.15} # groceries = 2.99 + 1.29
```

I'm very new to python learning it mainly through reading, so please pardon my simple question. I've struggled with this one for a while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
>>> {c: sum(dict2.get(p, 0) for p in items) for c, items in dict1.items()}
{'supplies': 3.15, 'groceries': 4.28}
```

Comment: thanks so much guys for the help! just as a follow up, would I be able to structure the code as follows, which is a bit more broken down? when I ran it, i get errors though...

`for c, items in dict1.items():`

    `for p in items:`

       `dict3 = {c: sum(dict2.get(p, 0))}`

unfortunately, I don't know how to format this more neatly here, but in IDLE, these codes are on separate lines and indented. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Simple dict comprehension:

```
dict3 = {category: sum(dict2.get(p, 0) for p in products) for category, products in dict1.items()}
```

Comment: @JuniorCompressor of course, I missed version tag. Fixed.